# Best Way to load model into redux store on route load

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-router, jwt

I have a React app that uses React-Router/React-Router-dom for page navigation and redux to store some global state info (jwt token for django rest framework for example).  The state also stores info about the currently viewed page, such as the serialized django model.

But what is the best way to load the django model into the redux store when the route changes?  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around where logic should be going.

If you view the repo below you can see where I'm having trouble figuring it out.

In this example when someone navigates to `/spells/:id`, it should load the `spell` django model into the redux store so information about it is globally accessible.

But how do I go about doing that?  Where do I call the actions and reducers to properly handle the state?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

You can view the full project [here](https://bitbucket.org/cclloyd9785/opensrd-fullstack/src/master/).  The component in question here is `LayoutSpellView` (`/frontend/src/components/LayoutSpellView`).  That's where the model information is stored, displayed, etc.

Edit:  Adding relevant code

Called in `componentDidMount`:

```
axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/api/spells/" + spellId)
    .then(response => {
        let spell = Object.assign({}, spellView.state.spell);

        spell.id =  response.data.id;
        spell.owner =  response.data.owner;
        ...blahblah other fields

        this.setState({
            spell
        });


    })
    .then(response => {
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_SPELL_SUCCESS',
            payload: this.state.spell,
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('[API]\t', error);
    });
```

In `LayoutSpellView` (same component as above)

```
import {loadSpell} from "../src/reducers";
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    spell: loadSpell(state.spell.id),
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    getSpell: (state.spell.id) => {
        dispatch(loadSpell(state.spell.id))
    }
});
```

Actions spell.js:

```
export const FETCH_SPELL = '@@spell/FETCH_SPELL';
export const FETCH_SPELL_SUCCESS = '@@spell/FETCH_SPELL_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_SPELL_FAILURE = '@@spell/FETCH_SPELL_FAILURE';

export const loadSpell = (spellId) => ({
    [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: '/api/spell/${spellId}',
        method: 'GET',
        types: [
            FETCH_SPELL, FETCH_SPELL_SUCCESS, FETCH_SPELL_FAILURE
        ]
    }
});
```

Reducers spell.js:

```
const initialState = {
    spell: {
        id: 0,
        owner: 0,
        Name: 'Name',
        School: 'unknown',
        Subschool: 'unknown',
    }
};
export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case spell_action.FETCH_SPELL_SUCCESS:
            return {
                spell: {
                    id: action.payload.spell.id,
                    owner: action.payload.spell.owner,
                    Name: action.payload.spell.Name,
                    School: action.payload.spell.School,
                    Subschool: action.payload.spell.Subschool,
                }
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function loadSpell(state) {
    if (state) {
        return state.spell
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably call an action in the component's `componentDidMount` to retrieve/store the data.

Comment: @NorianNyx I figured that much. That's actually where I have an axios call to retrieve it. But where in there and how do I call the action to push the new state from more than just local?

Comment: You would call it in the `.then` method of your axios call like: `this.props.dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_SUCCESS', payload: res.data })` (or whatever your pattern is for dispatching actions). Then in your reducer: `case 'RETRIEVE_SUCCESS': (state, action) => ({ ...state, action.payload })`

Comment: @NorianNyx I think I did that, but it keeps giving me errors that it's undefined.  I added the relevant bits of code to my question.  Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Is the payload undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the question in a different way. Instead of asking "How do I dispatch an action when routes change", let's ask "What is the actual source of truth: Redux or URL?"

If we go with `redux` being the Single Source of Truth, then that would mean that we need to `dispatch` some `action` that would cause some side-effect ( maybe `redux-saga` or `redux-observable` or even `redux-thunk`? ) that changed the url:

```
Comp -> dispatch(action) -> store updates -> URL changes
```

If we go with the URL being the Single Source of Truth, we change the flow to:

```
URL changes -> dispatch(action) -> store updates
```

If we go this route, which is what it sounds like you are wanting, you will need to probably hook up `middleware`, which are functions of the following signature:

```
store => next => action => next(action)
```

Depending on the router that you are using, you can either hook into their actions or you can hook into `window.onpopstate` and check the next url. Either way, the overall middleware function would look something like

```
const middleware = store => {
  return next => action => {
    if (actionWillCauseSpellToBeNeeded(action)) {
       makeAPICall()
         .then(transformAPIToAction)
         .catch(transformError)
         .then(store.dispatch) 
    }
    return next(action)
  }
}
```